# get the javascript variable value to Code Behind Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to pass the javascript variable value to hidden feild from code behind by onclientclick event.. i have button that have both client and server side onclick event

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"  class="buttonstyle" 
                onclick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="otherdata()" />
```

i want to get the javascript value in codebehind from OnClientClick event and then want to insert that value to database table from Onclick event

```
  function otherdata() {

                var hv = $('input[id$=hdnOthers]').val();
                    var $arrT = $('#<%=gv_Others.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtEmp"]');
                    var count = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        var $txt = $arrT[i];
                        count[i] = $($txt).val();

                    }
                    hv = count;
                    alert(hv);

            }
```

i am getting the value in alert and assigning the value to hidden field but problem is that i am not getting the value in hidden field from code behind.. although i have already pass the value to hidden field from javascript so why i am not getting that value from code behind..

```
protected void Insert_OtherServices()
    {
        dsJobCardTableAdapters.Select_OtherServiceTableAdapter dsother = new dsJobCardTableAdapters.Select_OtherServiceTableAdapter();

  string hdn = hdnOthers.Value;


        dsother.Insert_OtherService(hdn);

    }
```

Comment: hidden field is within gird view..?

Comment: @Bhavik it`s out side from gridview

Comment: @rene plz look at javasript function otherdata()... the variable hv in script is a hidden feild

Comment: @rene is there any difference between holding and assigning the value??? ok what should i do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assinging the value to your hidden field. Adapt your javascript like so:

```
function otherdata() {
   var hvField = $('input[id$=hdnOthers]');
   var $arrT = $('#<%=gv_Others.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtEmp"]');
   var count = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var $txt = $arrT[i];
        count[i] = $($txt).val();
   }
   // do notice you have an array that you assign
   // but you don't say the value of count is wrong for you
   // so I only fix the bug that you don't assign the value
   // to the hidden field
   hvField.val(count); // set the field to the value of Count
   alert(count);
}
```

See the [jquery doc for val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to use [Jquery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method.

Like this

```
function otherdata() {
   var hv = $('input[id$=hdnOthers]').val();
   var $arrT = $('#<%=gv_Others.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtEmp"]');
   var count = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       var $txt = $arrT[i];
       count[i] = $($txt).val();
   }

   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "YourASPXPage.aspx/Insert_OtherServices",
            data: {countVal : count},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function(response) {
                //alert(response.d);
            alert("Data saved succesfully");
       });
   //alert(hv);
}
```

and the method in code behind file now look like this, i mean its converted into **page method**, decorated with "WebMethod" attribute...

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string Insert_OtherServices(string countVal)
{
        dsJobCardTableAdapters.Select_OtherServiceTableAdapter dsother = new dsJobCardTableAdapters.Select_OtherServiceTableAdapter();

        string val = dsother.Insert_OtherService(countVal);
        return val;
}
```